# Why is javascript not executing on a web page when accessed via iOS Twitter browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, twitter, cross-browser

I am completely stumped and I'm sure this was working before.

I have a simple web page with the word "hello" in a div which does two things onload:

1) alert "2"

2) change the text of the div to "bye"

All vanilla Javascript, no libraries.

This works fine on the Chrome, IE, FF, Safari (as you'd expect). If I hit a link in the iOS Twitter app (latest version) to this web page neither of those two things happen. It seems to me that the Javascript is not being executed at all but how can this be? Has anyone else experienced this?

UPDATE

In fact vanilla Javascript will work. The alert test was misleading - I believe thats been disabled which is why it won't work. JQuery will not work however - possibly to do with the $ reference conflicting.

UPDATE 2

The problem has moved on now - my initial assumptions were not entirely correct.

The following code for a web page works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #test {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'vanilla javascript worked';
            $("#test").text("Jquery worked");
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="test">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following code does not work. The path to my script is sound and works on normal browsers, but when in the iOS Twitter in-app browser it seems the local script will not load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style>
        #test {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'vanilla javascript worked';
            $("#test").text("Jquery worked");
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="test">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested the issue on accessing the webpage via Facebook which also works fine either way. The problem is with the Twitter browser only on iOS.

I have tried using an absolute path to my script which also does not work.

UPDATE

This issue is not on iPad. It is iPhone only. As it was working before fine I'd say this is a bug from the latest release of the iPhone Twitter app. Will wait for a fix from Twitter.

Comment: Running into a twitter browser issue which has some similarities (only shows up on iPhone, not on iPad) but doesn't appear to be a js issue: we have a span with some text that just isn't being displayed.  Just wondering if you've learned anything about your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that I was re-writing all requests from Twitter to a pre-rendered html instance (brombone). So when it was looking for that file it was actually looking at the brombone server not mine.  I took out the rewrite and its fine now.

Completely unrelated to what I was going on about but I solved it nonetheless and may be a reminder to those with similar problems to look outside of the box and check server setups etc...